# Have a data message for Android and normal notification for IOS in single FCM request

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

Currently, I have different ways to handle notifications depending on if the system is Android or IOS, for Android, I send a data-only notification and create a local notification from it.

For IOS, since data-only notifications have no guarantee that they will be retrieved if the app is closed, I send a normal notification.

What I'm trying to do is having both notifications using the same FCM API call, here is my current json:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
        "d": "my_data",
    },
    "apns": {
        "headers": {
            "apns-priority": "10"
        },
        "payload": {
            "aps": {
                "alert": {
                    "title": "my title",
                    "body": "my body"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "priority": "high",
    "registration_ids": [...],
    "time_to_live":86400
}
```

So, what I expected from this request is that for android it would create a data only notification using:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
        "d": "my_data",
    }
}
```

And for IOS, it would create a normal notification using:

```json
{
    "notification": {
        "title": "my title",
        "body": "my body",
    }
}
```

This works for Android, but I don't receive this notification as a normal notification on IOS.. Shouldn't the `apns` payload be used for IOS in this case?

Comment: I am interested in a solution to this problem as well.

Comment: Just a consideration, what I do in my app is store which OS a token belongs to and that's all under a person's email. Then I perform the send in a loop for each stored token to the appropriate iOS or Android call.

Comment: Any luck? There is a bounty on my similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75958704/handling-data-notification-only-in-both-ios-and-android-fails

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue but I have got this working in Postman.  See JSON below.

```
{
    "message": {
        "token": "####FCMTOKEN#####",
        "android": {
            "priority": "high",
            "data": {
                "title": "title for android data",
                "body": "body for android data"
            }
        },
        "apns": {
            "headers": {
                "apns-push-type": "alert",
                "apns-priority": "10",
                "apns-topic": "####TOPIC####"
            },
            "payload": {
                "aps": {
                    "alert": {
                        "title": "Game Request",
                        "subtitle": "Five Card Draw",
                        "body": "Bob wants to play poker"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm very happy I found your response. Thank you.