# Handling data notification only in both iOS and Android fails

Tags: android, swift, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a server that sends push notifications. For Android, I override `onMessageReceived` to handle the message. For iOS, I use `NotificationExtension`. I **need** to change the incoming push notification (I don't know the title and everything server side, the client knows this). What is odd is that I can not find a way to make it work for both platforms. Here's the thing:

- For Android, the payload of the push notification must NOT contain a `notification` block. If there is a `notification` block present, the title and body of the `notification` will be shown when the app is in the background and the `onMessageReceived` is never called. This is not desired. Removing the `notification` block and just keep `data` works for Android for both background and foreground mode.
- When I omit the `notification` block for iOS, I get an error back from Firebase: `InvalidParameters: Invalid notification payload`.

**Examples**

Payload without `notification` (works fully for Android on background + foreground mode, fails to send (and thus retrieve) for iOS):

```
{
 "to" : "-",
 "data" : {
     "body" : "Notification Body",
     "title": "Notification Title",
 },
    "mutable_content": true
}
```

Payload with `notification`, this works fully for iOS but does not call the `onMessageReceived` method on Android when the app is in the background:

```
{
 "to" : "-",
 "data" : {
     "body" : "Notification Body",
     "title": "Notification Title",
 },
    "mutable_content": true,
    "notification": { "title": "test" }
}
```

How can I make both platforms work on foreground + background data push messages? According to https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#Notification, it states that it should be possible to send data notifications only to iOS, I tried to set the header but I still get the same error: "When sending payloads containing **only data fields to iOS devices**, only normal priority ("apns-priority": "5") is allowed in ApnsConfig."

**I don't want to use the content-available flag, since that behaves differently and you can only send 2 notification each hour.**

Comment: I also tried setting an `alert` inside the `payload` but I get the same error

Comment: remove notification block and add  ```  "apns": {
    "headers": {
      "apns-priority": "5"
    },
    "payload": {
      "aps": {
        "content-available": 1
      }
    }
  } ```

Comment: @udi that is only recommended for background updates, which my app doesn't. Check https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW8, they state it allows only a few each hour. This is not the way to go.

Comment: Same question asked here: [single FCM request for iOS and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71197177/have-a-data-message-for-android-and-normal-notification-for-ios-in-single-fcm-re)   

Seems like [customizing a message across platforms](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#customizing-a-message-across-platforms) does not work as before. Probably worth experimenting with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it was fixed by just adding  `"content_available" : true`

So the payload will be like

```
    {
     "to" : "-",
     "data" : {
         "body" : "Notification Body",
         "title": "Notification Title",
     },
        "mutable_content": true,
        "content_available" : true
    }
```

Comment: Note that this is a really poor solution since content_available will only allow 2 notifications an hour. I was using the old FCM, switching to FCM http 1 protocol solved the problem